# how to avoid data overflow issue when for-each data to table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

```
`let html=""
let html1=""
`allmatrixData ={f1:[{Id: 237, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccd', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f1",cashdiscount:250,categoryId: 1,priceCateName: "one by one sale",sellingPrice:2500 },{Id: 237, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccd', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f1",cashdiscount:225,categoryId: 2,priceCateName: "bulk sale",sellingPrice:2250},
{Id: 238, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccn', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f1",cashdiscount:500,categoryId: 1,priceCateName: "one by one sale",sellingPrice:5000},{Id: 238, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccn', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f1",cashdiscount:450,categoryId: 2,priceCateName: "bulk sale",sellingPrice:4500}] , f12:[
{Id: 239, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccd', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f12",cashdiscount:200,categoryId: 1,priceCateName: "one by one sale",sellingPrice:2000 },{Id: 239, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccd', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f12",cashdiscount:180,categoryId: 2,priceCateName: "bulk sale",sellingPrice:1800},
{Id: 240, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'ccn', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f12",cashdiscount:90,categoryId: 2,priceCateName: "bulk sale",sellingPrice:900},{Id: 238, attrNm1: 'cmd', attrNm1id: 68, attrvalue1: 'cmd', attrNm2: 'fit',attrNm2id
: 69,attrvalue2:"f12",cashdiscount:100,categoryId: 1,priceCateName: "one by one sale",sellingPrice:1000}]}


 //atribute 1 header section
         html+=`
            <tr class="border-0 bg bg-white">
            <th class="border-0 bg bg-white"></th>
            <th class="border-0 bg bg-white"></th>/
            <th class="border-0 bg bg-white"></th>
            <th class="border " colspan="`+ 2 * 2 +`">cmd</th>
            </tr>`   
    //atribute 1  values set
        html+=`
            <tr class="border-top-0">
                <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg bg-white" rowspan="2"></th>
                <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg bg-white" rowspan="2"></th>
                <th scope="col" class="border-top" rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Prices</th>`
            
                    html+=  `<th scope="col" class="border-top" colspan="2">ccd</th>
<th scope="col" class="border-top" colspan="2">ccn</th>`
          
        html+= `</tr>`;

        html+= `<tr>`;

    // credit and cash set
            html += `<th>Credit</th>
                     <th>Cash</th>
                     <th>Credit</th>
                     <th>Cash</th>`
 
        html+= `</tr>`;
  
    //attribute 2 name set
        html1+= `<tr>
            <th rowspan="`+pricecatelgnt*2+`" style="transform: rotate(270deg); writing-mode: vertical-lr;  text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">fit</th>`
    
            for (const key in allmatrixData) {
                      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(allmatrixData, key)) {
              const metrixPriceArray = allmatrixData[key];
              //attrubute 2 category set
              html1 += `<tr><th rowspan="1">${key}</th>`

            //priceses set 
               let id=0 ; 
                metrixPriceArray.forEach(val1 => {
                    id=val1.categoryId;
                    if (id!= val1.categoryId || id!=0){
                        html1+=  `<th>${val1.priceCateName}</th>`;
                        html1+=  `
                        <td>${val1.sellingPrice}</td>
                        <td>$(val1.sellingPrice - val1.cashdiscount}</td>` 
                    }
               
            });
            html1+=`</tr>`

            }
            }

  $("#tmxz thead").html(html);  // add data into table head 
  $("#tmxz tbody").html(html1);// add data into table body
``
```

I need to map above object to relative table so [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsbTf.png)  this image show what I tried approach. this is wrong so I need to make it rightly . [correct table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNVeG.png). this image show the right approach. please help me to solve the issue